# Deleted answer got stuck in server cache

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, caching

[Active questions list, page 4 as of right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4&sort=active):

> [image]

It's way over two days and the link points to [this deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178231/152859):

> [image]

What caused the answer to get stuck in the list? Lots of posts get deleted and cleared from the list just fine so can't see what happened here.

Comment: I think *any* post or edit activity will bump the question and retain the "modified by" message - even if the post is deleted. It's been like this for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Only page 4 if your settings are to show 30 per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edits on deleted answers and the undeletion of answers(not sure about deletion) bumps posts.  This is probably by design -- bumping is meant to invite review of a change from community members.

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason I thought it was cleared after a while when deleted. Guess you're right, will keep this post for others who will get confused.